# Говорю отцу: "Не могу..." (?) а он: "Можешь!"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, прямая-речь, тире

Что поставить перед союзом "а": запятую или тире?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если прямая речь заканчивается многоточием, то после кавычек ставится тире:

*Тут уж он и совсем обомлел: "Ваше благородие, батюшка барин, да как вы… да стою ли я…" — и заплакал вдруг* (Достоевский).
**Говорю отцу: "Не могу…" — а он: "Можешь!"**

[**Знаки препинания при прямой речи. Пункт в)**](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=442#pg442)

Запятая ставится в том случае, если прямая речь непосредственно включается в состав предложения (первое двоеточие отсутствует):
**Говорю отцу "Не могу…", а он: "Можешь!"**
[Там же, пункт г) ]

Запятая ставится и в том случае, если прямая речь оформляется как косвенная (кавычек нет):
**Говорю отцу, что не могу, а он: "Можешь!"**

P.S. Ваше предложение, как мне кажется, построено не совсем удачно. Оно трудно воспринимается, потому что обе фразы в кавычках находятся близко друг к другу (слова автора очень короткие). Гораздо лучше "смотрится" последний вариант.

**Дополнение** (примеры)

*Я ему кричу: «Слезай, слезай!» — а они бьют брата.*

*Я ему кричу: "Г-н Полковник, раздевайтесь!" — а он говорит мне: "Я не могу бросить полк".*
А. Судоплатов. Отрывки из дневника

*Глория поджарила ему баранью отбивную с оставшейся от обеда картошкой и спросила: «Они что, нашли твою черную бухгалтерию?» — и он мрачно рассмеялся: «Им никогда до меня не добраться, Глория», но впервые(...) в его голосе не было уверенности.*
К. Аткинсон. Поворот к лучшему

*...половину занимала подушка, затем Джексон пригляделся и решил, что это кошачье чучело, и едва в голове мелькнул вопрос: «Зачем вы набили кошку?» — чучело ожило.*
К. Аткинсон. Чуть свет, с собакою вдвоем

Comment: Здесь нет темы " Прямая речь внутри слов автора", здесь сложное предложение ССП, при этом каждое простое предложение имеет собственную прямую речь. Оформление независимое, поэтом двоеточие ставится.

Comment: Пример: Странный он все-таки человек, я ему говорю: «Может отразиться на производстве», а он отвечает: «Производство ― это люди». [И. Г. Эренбург. Оттепель (1953-1955)]

Comment: А я не мог понять, почему интуитивно мне это тире не нравится!

Comment: Можно предположить: если интонация вопросительная или восклицательная,  то она должна быть выражена в устной речи, поэтому требуется пауза, обозначаемая на письме тире.

Answer (score 1):

**Говорю отцу: “Не могу…”,  а он: “Можешь!”**

Перед противительным союзом обычно ставится запятая, так как значение противопоставления выражает сам союз.